# Angular: Ngx Scrollbar Parent with horizontal scroll having columns(children) with vertical scroll issues dragging horizontal across child w/ V-Scroll

Tags: angular, scrollbar

[image]

Hi,
I have drag and drop with Native HTML5 API, but when the column(child) which has vertical scroll enabled, i'm not able to drag item across it as the parent horizontal scrolls and child vertical scroll overlaps. i need the item in each column to be able to dragged across all the children(columns) irrespective of vertical scroll enabled or disabled.
The drag/ horizontal scroll stops when it encounters child with vertical scroll.
Note: I'm not using CDK lib for drag and drop.
TIA